# Geocoder : ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I read many things about this problem but I don't find an issue for the problem.
I've created a rake task that find all school in my DB, and find all premium-school. I want to display, thanks to Geocoder, the 3 nearest premiums school on non-premium school. But when I launch my task I have this error :

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)
/Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/origin-2.1.1/lib/origin/selectable.rb:334:in `near'
/Users/marchardantonin/Sites/Vroom2017/vroomvroom-web/lib/tasks/geocodeschool.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:668:in `yield_document'
```

Here is the code :

**geocoderschool.rake**

```
namespace :geocodeschool do
  desc "Show premium school near non-premium school and update them"
  task :schgc => :environment do
      @schools = School.all
      @schools_premium = @schools.premium_school
      radius = 30
      @schools.each do |school|
        @schools_aside = @schools_premium.near(school.coordinates.reverse, radius, units: :km).limit(3)
        puts "les auto-écoles premiums : #{@shcools_aside.count}"
        puts "-------"
        @schools_aside.each do |sa|
          puts sa.title
        end
        puts "-------"
    end
  end
end
```

**school.rb**

```
  scope :premium_school, -> {where(:subscription.exists => true).where("subscription.current_period_end" => {'$gte' => Date.today})}

  embeds_one :geocodeschool
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :geocodeschool
```

**geocodeschool.rb**

```
class Geocodeschool
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :school

  field :school_premium_aside, type: Array

end
```

Does someone could explain me the error and help me to find an issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think `near` should be called on `PremiumSchool` model, sending the coordinates in `@schools_premium`

Comment: @Sravan Thank ! I applied the method on `School`, and passing the premium argument after the localisation

Comment: okay, still the error persists?

Comment: whats the status now? resolved?

Comment: @Sravan Yes it's resolved ! many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocode's `near` method should be called on a model, sending the coordinates.

So, call it on `PremiumSchool` model,and send the coordinates in @schools_premium

**`@schools_aside = School.near(@schools_premium.coordinates.reverse, radius, units: :km).limit(3)`**

[Here is the documentation.](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at the [official documentations](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/origin/2.1.1/Origin/Selectable#near-instance_method) for that gem. It only accepts a hash as arguments, such as:

```
@schools_premium.near(location: [ 23.1, 12.1 ])
```

Having a look at the [Mongoid code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/608578f9256752cc48706b7774415cc8739fdacc/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb), it seems like you should be using `geo_near` as such:

```
@schools_premium.geo_near(school.coordinates.reverse).max_distance(0.5)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, How can I pass radius and units ?

Comment: Updated the answer, its untested, but it should get you started with.